# Cannot import tensorflow after a week of no use, no changes was made

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

What I've did:

1. uninstall and `pip install tensorflow-macos`
2. uninstall `pip install tensorflow-metal`
3. `import tensorflow as tf`

The expected result is no error.

However, I got an error after importing tensorflow.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
      3 # from keras import datasets, layers, models
      4 # import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py:37
     34 import sys as _sys
     35 import typing as _typing
---> 37 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     38 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     40 # Make sure code inside the TensorFlow codebase can use tf2.enabled() at import.

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py:45
     43 from tensorflow.python import distribute
     44 # from tensorflow.python import keras
---> 45 from tensorflow.python.feature_column import feature_column_lib as feature_column
     46 # from tensorflow.python.layers import layers
     47 from tensorflow.python.module import module

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_lib.py:18
     15 """FeatureColumns: tools for ingesting and representing features."""
     17 # pylint: disable=unused-import,line-too-long,wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order
---> 18 from tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column import *
...
   (...)
   3248     :returns: The PKCS12 object
   3249     """

TypeError: deprecated() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

Comment: Maybe do all your uninstall's before _any_ re-install.

Comment: You can verify the system [build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#macos) here and try running the code again. As you have installed python 3.10, then the TensorFlow version should be `>=2.8`. Please re-install the TensorFlow if needed by following the steps mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos).